# Weingarten equation $\overline{D}_U X = B_U X + \nabla_U X$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:(M, g) \rightarrow (N, h)$ be a pseudo-Riemannian immersion, $\overline D$ the linear connection on $f^*(TN)$ induced from the Levi-Civita connection of $h$, and $\nabla$ the connection induced on the normal bundle $NM$ (which is the orthogonal complement of $TM$ in $f^*(TN)$). Consider also the second fundamental form
$$\mathrm{II}: TM\otimes TM\rightarrow NM$$
given by
$$\mathrm{II}(U,V) = \mathcal N(\overline D_U V),$$
where $\mathcal N$ is the orthogonal projection onto $NM$. Finally, let the tensor $B:TM\otimes NM \rightarrow TM$ be given by $g(B_U X, V) = -g(\mathrm{II}(U,V)X)$.

Then, how can I prove the Weingarten Equation
$$\overline{D}_U X = B_U X + \nabla_U X,$$
c.f. Arthur Besse’s “Einstein Manifolds” p. 38 Theorem 1.72 b)?

Comment: You need to read some standard differential/Riemannian geometry texts before reading Besse. Learn DoCarmo or Spivak volumes 2 and 3.